# Books written using TeX

Tags: books, tex-general

As part of my research I need to find the detailed list of books written using TeX, LaTeX.... I am from Computer Science background, and found some books written making use of TeX, LaTeX... Could you please give a list of books written using this. I know the list is large. It would be ok to include major titles only.

Comment: Apart from the fact that this question doesn't really have an answer: ("the" detailed list simply doesn't exist) it's not clear that it's really an appropriate for the site. It's really only marginally on topic.

Comment: Regardless of the mentioned goals in this question, people like to watch examples, so having even far incomplete list of published books (I would avoid e-books in this case, because that would be too much) prepared in *TeX as a _community wiki_ would be surely nice for newcomers and others, who could go to (local) bookstore or library and check effects of TeX used in real world. Just saying.

Comment: You could start with (nearly) all university level math books published in the last few decades. This alone should net you a few thousand examples...

Comment: nelson beebe (at the university of utah) has compiled several bibliographies of books prepared with tex, in the form of bibtex files.  the file `http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub//tex/bib/texbook2.html` contains mostly references to books published through 1994 (at which point tex had become ubiquitous in several fields) and only significant books later on.  it also contains pointers to a couple of other relevant bib files.

Comment: I converted this question to a community wiki now. As @Alan Munn already stated it doesn't fit in the normal Q&A scheme of this site. It might however be closed anyway soon (4 votes already, 5 required).

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1319/627) will be somewhat relevant.

Answer (score 5):

Searching MathSciNet for all books published between 1990 and 2011 came up with a list 41721 items. That would make a good start for your list.

Answer (score 1):

All my books were formatted using [La]TeX (authored in SGML/XML and converted):

The World Wide Web Handbook (Thompson, 1995) 1850322058
Understanding SGML and XML Tools (Kluwer, 1998) 0792381696
Formatting Information (TUG, 2002; Silmaril, 2011) http://latex.silmaril.ie/

I agree this is not the appropriate place for a list, but I think a centralised list would be a useful resource.

P

Comment: It’s really off topic but I’d like to ask you if you know any about converting (La)TeX to (good) XML? If I understood you converted the other way, from XML to TeX. If you have some information for me it would be kind to send me an e-mail (see the address in my profile). Or I’ll open a new question to make it available for the others.

Comment: Pandoc seems to be the best at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I recently published [a theology book](http://www.lulu.com/product/paperback/calvinisme-arminianisme-parole-de-dieu/16426878) done in LaTeX (and more coming). There's a free PDF download link on the page.