# Are there fiction novels written in LaTeX?

Tags: tex-general

Are there fiction novels written in LaTeX?

I am not interested in technical books, but in proper fictional novels.

Comment: The books by [Nicola Talbot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot) would be a good guess [Dickimaw Books: The Private Enemy](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/fiction/crime/the-private-enemy/) (the sample on the website is definitely created in pdfLaTeX, Nicola will be able to confirm on the actual book) and [Quack, Quack, Quack. Give My Hat Back!](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/fiction/kids/duck/)

Comment: This question is sort of meta, nicht wahr?

Comment: I seem to recall an appendix to one of Neal Stephenson's novels describing his production process, which involved LaTeX, but then the publisher converted everything to Quark. But I could be thinking of a different author.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Not really meta as in dealing with the site behaviour. I think this is off-topic.

Comment: This doesn't seem any more off-topic than, say, [Books written using TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21861/books-written-using-tex) which was closed as a duplicate of [Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends) rather than being off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, my crime fiction novel was typeset using LaTeX with [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir), [`microtype`](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) and [`lettrine`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lettrine). The font was [TeX Gyre Termes](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/tgtermes/). The document also used [`glossaries`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries), which admittedly isn't quite so common for novels.

My children's fiction books used the [`extarticle`](http://ctan.org/pkg/extsizes) class with [`flowfram`](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) to layout the pages. There's a little more [information about the production process](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/fiction/kids/duck/#production) for one of them that had double-page spread images.

I've also used LaTeX for poetry, short stories, correspondence, designing posters, art exhibition catalogues, and pretty much most things that require putting text on a page. If I'm feeling really lazy I may use LibreOffice to write a single line of large text on a sheet of paper (such as "Entrance", "Exit" etc) where I can't be bothered to even save the file but in those situations I sometimes simply resort to using a big marker pen.

Comment: Plus one by somehow bashing LO by using a marker pen :-D

Answer (score 3):

Why limit yourself to novels? I have seen LaTeXed books such as fairy stories, poetry, exploration, prayer, quotations, etc. Not necessarily printed and available from bookshops but some being privately printed for friends and family of the LaTeXers.

On occasions I do traditional letterpress printing and always produce a LaTeX version of the text before setting any type to see how the layout will turn out (do I need to lengthen/shorten the text block? do I need to make it wider/narrower? etc).

I write all my non-email correspondence using LaTeX.